# Finding a change in a signal

Tags: filters, noise, continuous-signals, c, pattern

I am looking to some C algorithm(for MCU), where I have these signals :
[image]

**First** graph you can see that there is an event in the middle and it goes back to normal, **second** and **third** there is some event at a certain point.
Any of them can happen per session(= when I turn the device there will be 1 behavior)

I have to find  *real time* when the event begin and ends, and it has to be **FAST**.

1. All maximums in all 3 graphs are more or less the same (with 2% diff)
2. I don't know the values before hand but I can calibrate the "no event" state.
3. I need 1 algorithm to all of them.

I can do all sorts of basic stuff with averages and LPF, but I guess there is more clever and generic way to do so (?)

Something that can cover all cases and do what my eyes do - I can just tell where is the event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure about:

1. Noise power is bounded
2. The power of the signal step is higher than *4 times* that noise power.

If the noise power is bounded and the change in the signal level is higher than 4 times that noise power (from the pictures it seems to be so, I mean, the step is more than twice the max value of noise), why not take the derivative of the signal? something like:

```
step = abs(x[n] - x[n-1]);
if (step > threshold)
{
  // Event has happened: 
  // 1. Take timer value
  event_time = get_time();
  // 2. Update the state machine
  state = (state == START_STATE) ? STOP_STATE : START_STATE;
}
```

Well, the `get_timer()` is specific to your MCU and there are better ways to implement a *Finite State Machine*, but that is the idea. It is fast and fulfills the requirements, I would not go further.

Comment: This may fail, becaus the signal is zigzag you might take the top of it right befor the jump and then the bottom, which may be close.

Comment: Could you assign some numbers to *the top of it right before the jump* and *the bottom* to give me a counterexample?

Comment: @Curnelious : Oh, I see now what you mean, there was a *2* missed over there. Please, check my edit.